# Ubuntu 16.04 installation in HP notebook

Tags: boot

I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 on a HP Notebook on a separate partition to Windows 8.

Ubuntu installed with any error, but after installation, it is starting with windows 8 with out showing the dual boot menu

Answer (score 0):

That's probably related to `secure boot`, or the uefi is setup to boot in windows. You should be able to configure the boot system from the firmware/bios, or from windows.
Did you try to access the `boot order` menu when booting?
More info:

- http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Disabling_SecureBoot_in_the_BIOS